# How to set gridview template fields in right side?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a gridview with template fields.Now all template fields are showing in the left side of gridview. How can I set it to the right side? My gridview is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="18" CellPadding="10"   runat="server"> 
<Columns >
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server">Single OT</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server">Double OT</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

And also binding a query with this gridview. My Query is

```
qry="select OT from OverTime where EmpCode=@EmpCode"
dr=conn.query(qry);
GridView1.DataSource = dr;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: you mean the text inside the fields is aligned left?

Comment: @Irfan TahirKheli, No only the linkbuttons should be placed in right side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youcan use the `ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign` attribute:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
```

Comment: Nope, I changed but still its in left side

Comment: I am binding a query with gridview

Comment: @MohanLal try to add `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` to the `GrdiView` and a `Width` to the columns.

Comment: no way.Now gridview shows only template fields not showing query result

Comment: @MohanLal of course, but control inside the templatefield are aligned to right?

Comment: but I need the query result also

Comment: @MohanLal but are the controls inside thos columns aligned to right? If yes the problem is solved man! About the columns from your query, manually create a `BoundField` for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

For particular Template Column you can add **ItemStyle** tag like,

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

so that the content within that particular Template Column gets aligned towards right

Hope this helps!!